# Jquery: how to produce 1 of 3 phrases when event happens

Tags: jquery, math, random, phrases

I have a bookmarking feature on my site, when the person clicks a paragraph, the box that is already hovering over that paragraph that reads "bookmark this" inserts "sweet man" in place of "bookmark this". so 'bookmark this' disappears and "sweet man" takes its place, how would i make it so when i click on the paragraph, it places 1 of 3 random phrases in there, lets say the 3 phrases are "success", "sweet man", and "awesome". here's a little bit of my code to show you where the random phrase would be placed.

```
 $('p').click(function (e) {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
     var top = offset.top

     if ($('#placeBookmark').hasClass('placing')) { 
      $('#placeBookmark').trigger('click')

    $('#bookmark').css({left: offset.left - 30, top: top}).show();
     $('#bookmarkThis').html('***SWEET MAN.***').delay(1000).fadeOut(400, function(){
        $(this).html('BOOKMARK THIS')
         })

    }
});
```

See where in my code it says "SWEET MAN.", that's where the 1 of 3 random phrases should be placed after the user clicks the paragraph.

THANK-YOU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('p').click(function (e) {
  var offset = $(this).offset();
  var top = offset.top

  // list of phrases
  var phrases = ["success", "sweet man", "awesome"];

  if ($('#placeBookmark').hasClass('placing')) { 
    $('#placeBookmark').trigger('click')

    $('#bookmark').css({left: offset.left - 30, top: top}).show();

    // Selects a random phrase from the list.
    // Note that it doesn't require the length to be exactly three,
    // you can add and remove phrases above without changing this line.
    var selectedPhrase = phrases[Math.floor(Math.random() * phrases.length)]; 

    $('#bookmarkThis').html(selectedPhrase).delay(1000).fadeOut(400, function(){
      $(this).html('BOOKMARK THIS')
    })
  }
});
```

**Edit**

As a separate function:

```
var getRandomPhrase = function() {
  var phrases = ["success", "sweet man", "awesome"];
  return phrases[Math.floor(Math.random() * phrases.length)];
};
```

Or with the phrases are arguments:

```
var getRandomPhrase = function(phrases) {
  return phrases[Math.floor(Math.random() * phrases.length)];
};
```

Use it like this:

```
...
$('#bookmarkThis').html(getRandomPhrase()).delay(1000).fadeOut(400, function(){
...
```

or, when phrases are used as arguments:

```
...
$('#bookmarkThis').html(getRandomPhrase(["success", "sweet man", "awesome"])).delay(1000).fadeOut(400, function(){
...
```

Comment: excellent! if i'm going to do this throughout my site, having random phrases when different things happen, would it be wise to take "var selectedPhrase" out of the $('p').click function? how would i make it so all i have to do in this click function is reference selectedPhrase as you did with ".html(selectedPhrase)" and provide the phrases? so: how would i make this into a function? if it's not too much trouble. thanks!

Comment: It is absolutely a good idea to break it out into a function of its own. I'll edit my answer to provide an alternative solution!